# enable window 'snap' in 12.04 (window maximation on drag to edge)

Tags: window-manager, window

I have recently updated to 12.04. The feature which maximises the window if dragged to the upper screen edge, taking the right half if dragged to the right edge and so on, is now missing. (I'm coming from version 11.10)

I haven't done any major modifications on the OS and tried several tutorials for enabling this behaviour with compiz.

Is this feature gone forever? If not, how to re-enable it? It was extremely helpful for programming and I do not want to have some kind of workaround with keyboard shortcuts. But if it's not possible with mouse dragging, how can I enable some shortcut?

if you need additional information about my system configuration, please let me know with instructions about how to get this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The feature which maximizes the window when dragged to the upper panel is still present, but only in Unity 3D, not in Unity 2D.

Therefore, I would suggest to check if you have the right graphics drivers, because when you don't, Ubuntu will automatically start the Unity-2D session instead of the default, heavy unity.

I did a clean install and tried Unity 3D after installing my nvidia drivers.

Comment: I see how this could indeed be the solution. I will accept this answer when I finally have found the solution to the ATI driver installation..

Comment: thank you very much. after the nightmare of installing ati drivers it works fine now :)

Comment: How do I check if Unity 3D is enabled or not? I have a proprietary nVidia driver installed which seems to work (WebGL works).